# Decompress lots of small files and compressing them again for efficiency and avoid S3 API costs

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, compression, jobs

I've 1B+ gzip files (avg. 50 kb per each) and I want to upload them into S3 server. As I need to pay for each write operation, it becomes a huge cost problem to transfer them into S3. Also, those files are very similar and I want to compress them within a large file, so that compression efficiency will increase too.

I'm a newbie when it comes to write shell scripts but looking for a way, where I can:

- Find all .gz files,
- Decompress first 1K,
- Compress in a single folder,
- Delete this 1K batch,
- Iterate to next 1K file,

I appreciate if you able to help me to think more creatively to do this. The only way in my mind is decompressing all of them and compress them by each 1K chunks, but it is not possible as I don't have disk space to compress them.

Comment: What do you mean by *"it is not possible as I don't have disk space to **compress** them"*? You don't have enough space to store all the *new*, bigger .gz files? Or you just don't have enough space to **de**compress all 1B files at once? For the latter, your described approach of processing 1k chunks seems fine, although I would make the chunks bigger (1k*50kB = 50MB, probably way less than that, since you said the files are very similar. I would make the chunks as big as possible).

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/beingunresponsive

Answer (score 0):

Test with a few files how much additional space is used when decompressing files. Try to make more free space (move 90% of the files to another host).
When files are similar the compression rate of 10% of the files will be high.
I guess that 10 chunks will fit, but it will be tight everytime you want to decompress one. So I would go for 100 chunks.
But first think what you want to do with the data in the future.
Never use it? Delete it.
Perhaps 1 time in the far future? Glacier.
Often? Use smaller chunks so you can find the right file easier.